# Is there a name for graph regions that lie between two nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

Perhaps a bit more formally, is there a name for regions delimited by nodes A and B, in a directed graph, where all paths starting from A, when prolonged, will eventually reach B, and all paths reaching B are crossing A, or start from a node that is reachable from A?

EDIT: Hopefully more precisely, thanks to the comment:

I am interested in subgraphs $H(A,B)$ of $G$, with $A \in G, B \in G$:

1. $\forall v \in H$, $v$ is reachable from $A$,
2. $\forall v \in H$, $B$ is reachable from $v$,
3. $\forall x \in G, x \notin H, v \in H$, if $v$ is reachable from $x$, then all paths between $x$ and $v$ must cross $A$,
4. $\forall x \in G, x \notin H, v \in H$, if $x$ is reachable from $v$, then all paths between $v$ and $x$ must cross $B$.

Given a node $A$, there can be several valid subgraphs $H(A,B)$. In the set of all valid subgraphs, I am interested in the one that minimizes the distance between $A$ and $B$ (I believe it unique in my use case).

Illustration:

In [This graph](https://www.projectaon.org/en/svg/lw/02fotw.svgz), the following graphs are examples of what I am looking for:

- $H(001,160)$, containing nodes $001, 160, 273$;
- $H(160,300)$, containing nodes $160, 255, 203, 016, 048, 133, 268, 348, 333, 125, 067, 300$

The subgraph between node $160$ and $333$ doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: The union of all shortest paths from A to B is sometimes called an "interval", but it's not quite the same thing,

Comment: Firstly, what is a "region" here? Obviously it's a subgraph, but is it an induced subgraph? Secondly, if the original graph is $G$ and the "region" is $H$, are the quantifiers over $G$ or $H$? In other words, does "*all paths starting from A...*" mean all paths in $G$ or all paths in $H$? Similarly "*all paths reaching B*".

Comment: Followup which occurs to me: if $H$ is an induced subgraph then I think the first condition would be that if vertex $v \in H$ is reachable from $A$ then $B$ is reachable from $v$, and the second condition would be that if $B$ is reachable from $v$ then $v$ is reachable from $A$. But the title of this question says "*that lie between two nodes*". Is the intention really that every $v \in H$ should be reachable from $A$ and $B$ should be reachable from $v$?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough with graph theory to know what an induced subgraph is. However, your second definition seems to fit what I want!

Comment: I realized I also need be $H$ to be the smallest possible ... will update the question.

Comment: Induced subgraph: if two vertices are in $H$ and there's an edge between them in $G$ then we keep the edge in $H$. If it's just "a subgraph" rather than "an induced subgraph" we can discard some of those edges. If $H$ is the smallest possible subgraph (induced or otherwise) which contains $A$ and $B$ and for which every vertex $v$ is on a path from $A$ to $B$ then it's just a single shortest path. Is that your intention?

Comment: I am afraid I am not too good at this, I updated the question and added an example, hopefully making my intention clear.

Comment: Your example looks like a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Is that always the case? It's also not clear to me how a subgraph minimizes distance. And it's odd that for you a "subgraph" is a set of vertices: do you mean the subgraph induced by the vertices (I don't think you ever answered Peter's question.)

Comment: There are cycles in the graph i linked, and in the general case I work with directed graphs. As for the question, no, it's not the shortest path. I *think* I mean the graph induced by the listed vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds similar to *superbubbles* in bioinformatics.

We have a directed graph $G = (V, E)$. A superbubble is an induced subgraph defined by vertices $s, t \in V$ (with $s \ne t$). We have the following requirements:

- Vertex $t$ is reachable from $s$.
- The subgraph is induced by the set of vertices $U \subseteq V$ reachable from $s$ without passing through (first entering and then leaving) $t$.
- $U$ is also the set of vertices from which $t$ is reachable without passing through $s$.
- The subgraph is acyclic.
- The superbubble is minimal: no other vertex $t' \in U$ (with $t' \ne t$) defines a superbubble with vertex $s$.

Onodera, Sadakane, and Shibuya: **Detecting Superbubbles in Assembly Graphs**. [WABI 2013](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-40453-5_26), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7925).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!